# Spring Cloud Config + Spring Cloud Bus + RabbitMQ - Not auto refreshing clients with local Git repository

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I have some applications getting its configuration from a Spring Cloud Config Server (**Brixton.RELEASE**) and would like to enable the auto refresh of its properties. I have followed Spring Cloud Config [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config) to configure both the server and client apps but, when making changes on the local git files nothing happens.

> the default configuration also detects filesystem changes in local git
>   repositories (the webhook is not used in that case but as soon as you
>   edit a config file a refresh will be broadcast).

Can anybody point out what could be wrong or where to debug in Spring Cloud's code to check it?

**Spring cloud Server Config**:

```
server:
  port: 8888

info:
  description: Spring Cloud Config Server

spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///C:/Users/myuser/git/config-dev/
```

**Spring Cloud Server pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Spring Cloud Config Startup logs**:

```
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel springCloudBusInput
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=springCloudBusInput': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=springCloudBusInput]
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel springCloudBusOutput
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=springCloudBusOutput': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=springCloudBusOutput]
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel]
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel]
o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorLogger,bean=internal': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorLogger,bean=internal]
o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
o.s.c.s.binding.BindableProxyFactory     : Binding outputs for :interface org.springframework.cloud.bus.SpringCloudBusClient
o.s.c.s.binding.BindableProxyFactory     : Binding :interface org.springframework.cloud.bus.SpringCloudBusClient:springCloudBusOutput
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@707ca986: startup date [Fri May 13 10:03:10 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$73faa1d3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
e.m.a.config.ConfigServerApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1ca610a0: startup date [Fri May 13 10:03:11 CEST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@294a6b8e
o.s.c.support.GenericApplicationContext  : Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6048e26a: startup date [Fri May 13 10:03:11 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
e.m.a.config.ConfigServerApplication     : Started ConfigServerApplication in 2.907 seconds (JVM running for 12.366)
o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: SimpleConnection@7bbcf6f0 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler:outbound.springCloudBus} as a subscriber to the 'springCloudBusOutput' channel
o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'config-server:8888.springCloudBusOutput' has 1 subscriber(s).
o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started outbound.springCloudBus
o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'config-server:8888.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147482647
o.s.c.s.binding.BindableProxyFactory     : Binding inputs for :interface org.springframework.cloud.bus.SpringCloudBusClient
o.s.c.s.binding.BindableProxyFactory     : Binding :interface org.springframework.cloud.bus.SpringCloudBusClient:springCloudBusInput
o.s.c.s.b.r.RabbitMessageChannelBinder   : declaring queue for inbound: springCloudBus.anonymous.t4cuHSE6RfKRYvPvrgfbUg, bound to: springCloudBus
o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'springCloudBus.anonymous.t4cuHSE6RfKRYvPvrgfbUg.bridge' has 1 subscriber(s).
o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : started inbound.springCloudBus.anonymous.t4cuHSE6RfKRYvPvrgfbUg
```

**Client App pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Client App config**:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

**Client App Startup log**:

```
o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping  INFO - Mapped "{[/bus/refresh],methods=[POST]}" onto public void org.springframework.cloud.bus.endpoint.RefreshBusEndpoint.refresh(java.lang.String)
...
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Registering MessageChannel springCloudBusInput
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=springCloudBusInput': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=springCloudBusInput]
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Registering MessageChannel springCloudBusOutput
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=springCloudBusOutput': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=springCloudBusOutput]
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel]
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel]
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=org.springframework.cloud.bus.BusAutoConfiguration.acceptRemote.serviceActivator,bean=endpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=org.springframework.cloud.bus.BusAutoConfiguration.acceptRemote.serviceActivator,bean=endpoint]
o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter  INFO - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorLogger,bean=internal': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorLogger,bean=internal]
o.s.b.a.e.j.EndpointMBeanExporter  INFO - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
```

Comment: Did you commit the changes?

Comment: Yes I also tried commiting, although it shouldn't be necessary, the doc states that it checks the file system...

Comment: Only with the native profile, not with git.

Comment: @spencergibb I set `spring.application.profiles.active= native` and `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///C:/Users/myuser/git/config-dev/` but still nothing is refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to go through this documentation [spring-cloud-config-push-notifications](https://spencer.gibb.us/blog/2015/09/24/spring-cloud-config-push-notifications/) and do not forget to install ngrock. Also if you just need to refresh on git commit then you do not even need cloud-bus project just config should be enough. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the use of ngrok, it served me to test against a real GitHub repo instead of the file system.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a Config server with Spring Cloud Bus and RabbitMQ (or Kafka or Redis) support.

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

RabbitMQ with the following exchange:

**name**: springCloudBus

**type**: topic

**durable**: true

**autoDelete**: false

**internal**: false

The Config server would send data to the topic once it receives push events from any of Github, Bitbucket or GitLab, via a webhook to http://<config-server>/monitor

And a client application with Config and RabbitMQ libraries:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

Subscribed to the previous exchange to receive messages with the properties that need to be refreshed.

More could be found in my blog at: http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html with a brief explanation of the configuration, logs and full source code for the Config server and client app.

Comment: Looks like I can use same (pub/sub mechanism) for updating JMX manage beans/configurations. Or is there better way of centralizing JMX management in cluster environment?

Comment: ootero: I was following your blog and make my service client (run on local machine) refresh when change push to git. I want to use same concept on pcf, which is using pcf rabbitmq service. How can I inject pcf service into service client. On local, I config rabbitmq:
  rabbitmq:
    host: ....

On pcf,pivotal put rabbitmq on this json:
{
...

credential: {
  host: ...
  ....
}
....
}

Answer (score 0):

You need have fallowing dependent in the pom.xml
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit') - Gradle 
if you have hosed you rabbitmq in the another system you need to specify the host file in the application.properties

spring.rabbitmq.host: {{hostname}}